# How can I confirm ref.removeAllObservers() has completed?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm looking for something similar to a Firebase [completion block](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-Block) to confirm that my I've removed all Firebase callbacks before I switch to the next ViewController

```
ref.removeAllObservers()
let resultController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! UIViewController
self.presentViewController(resultController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: There is no "show me all registered observers" method in the Firebase API. That said: if you are stuck with lingering observers, you probably registered them in a child node, but only called `removeAllObservers` on the top-level ref. You'll have to remove each observer from the exact ref/child where you initially registered it. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/off.html: "Calling off() on a parent listener will not automatically remove listeners registered on child nodes, off() must also be called on any child listeners to remove the callback."

Comment: Thanks Frank! This is a huge help. I wasn't removing observers on the child node - that was the major mistake

Comment: Yeah, we recently expanded that section in the web API docs, since it's an easy mistake to make. We should also document it for iOS and Android. I'll add my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "show me all registered observers" method in the Firebase API.

That said: if you are stuck with lingering observers, you probably registered them in a child node, but only called `removeAllObservers` on the top-level ref. You'll have to remove each observer from the exact ref/child where you initially registered it.

See the [web docs for `off`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/off.html):

> Calling `off()` on a parent listener will not automatically remove listeners registered on child nodes, `off()` must also be called on any child listeners to remove the callback.

Answer (score 3):

What makes you think that observers are not removed during `removeAllObservers()` call, that this operation is asynchronous and that you should wait for something? It's not necessary, it's synchronous operation.

Generally, do not remove observers with `removeAllObservers()`, because in this way you can remove observers added by another classes as well. It's better to keep array of `FirebaseHandle`s somewhere and remove them one by one when not needed.

[Detaching Blocks](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-detaching) describes it.

Comment: Thanks Robert! Keeping an array of FirebaseHandles makes sense. My main issue was that I was running removeAllObservers at the top level and it wasn't switching off my child node callbacks.